# How to change folder properties inside a sharepoint library

Tags: document-library, folder, properties

We have an existing SharePoint library that was created years ago for project management. The users who used to manage it are no longer with the company.

The library is setup with multiple folders. The users who have left the company had some way of assigning values to the library columns for these folders.

For example, There is a column "Active" that indicates whether the project is active or not. Some of the folders are marked "Yes" for this column. I cannot figure out how they edited that field. Regular documents allow me to check out the document, and edit the field, folders do not. The column is grayed out in datasheet view, and missing from the properties form.

Is there someway to do this through the GUI, or were they likely using a 3rd party product to make the change?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have permissions? Perhaps they used PowerShell? When you say "years ago" I assume we're talking SP 2007?

http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2007/09/03/preparing-powershell-for-sharepoint-and-moss-2007/

http://www.powershell.nu/2009/09/08/moss-2007-script-collection/

Here's a start. Hope that helps.

==================================================================

ADDITION:

Get the collection:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.folders.aspx

Get the folder:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.aspx

Change the properties:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.properties.aspx

The Object Model in PowerShell is the same as the SharePoint Server Object Model, just the syntax is different.

http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/my-sharepoint-2010-powershell-tutorial-for-sharepoint-200-developers/

PowerShell is critical for any SharePoint admin to learn, so now's as good a time as any.

Comment: Yes- this was likely converted from 2007. But, it was edited as recently as 6 months ago- after we converted to 2010. As far as permissions, I am a site admin, and have full rights. It is only the folders that I can't set some values for.

Comment: I know this is old but.... I have been experimenting with Sharepoint online and I set this exact thing up (with the active column against folders). Yesterday I was setting  these column values up. Today I cannot find out where I did this. There's nothing on the web UI that lets me set this active property even though I was only doing this yesterday.